# On map load / Page load i want to set map to the current geolocation but dont want to show locate icon on map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am working on map box and i want to show current location of user on map or page load on map For that i am using locate() control but i dont want to show locate icon on map.
Below is my code.

```
 this.map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {}).
 locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 10});
 var lc = L.control.locate().addTo(this.map);
 lc.start();
```

This code is adding locate control on map , I just want to hide it.

Comment: if you work on map box why there is  the google-maps tag in your post .. please remove the improper tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to locate the user but not show a control, you can not use the control and use the map's built-in [locate method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate). There's an example for how to use it for exactly this purpose in [the Mobile Tutorial under Geolocation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html).